# QGIS 3.4 Modeler gives error on non-required parameter?

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-modeler, parameters

I created a model which is asking to input 20 OPTIONAL parameters for vector layers.

[image: Example for one parameter]

But when the user does not enter a value for any of the 20 parameters, QGIS returns an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\PointsLayerFromTable.py", line 91, in processAlgorithm
raise QgsProcessingException(self.invalidSourceError(parameters, self.INPUT))
_core.QgsProcessingException: Cannot load source layer for INPUT: invalid Value
```

Note: I translated the last line.

Is there a way, to not enter a value for some of the parameters and still have the ones processed that do have values?